# Why should I not use object_setIvar to set properties

Tags: ios, objective-c, objective-c-runtime

I have a dictionary containing data for user from a REST endpoint. Here is my user class

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface User : NSObject

@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *uid;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *email;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *firstName;
@property (strong, nonatomic) NSString *lastName;
@property (assign, nonatomic) int status;

@end
```

I have a method to set all properties

```
/*
 * set properties
 */
- (void)setPropertiesWithDictionary:(NSDictionary *)dictionary{
    for(NSString *key in dictionary){

        object_setIvar(self,
                       class_getInstanceVariable([self class], [[@"_" stringByAppendingString:key] UTF8String]),
                       dictionary[key]);
    }
}
```

Instead of doing something like
`[user setUid:@dictionary[@"uid"]];`

I want to call my method like this
`[user setPropertiesWithDictionary: dictionary];`

Just wondering if implementing `object_setIvar` this way is fine. If not - Would be really great if you can explain why. Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why do you not think it would be fine?

Comment: I haven't seen any example of this. More like the Variable variables concept. Just messing around and pushing Objective-C boundaries basically.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do whatever you like, but why reinvent the wheel when key value coding (KVC) already exists? Just call this method:

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/objectivec/nsobject/1417515-setvaluesforkeyswithdictionary?language=objc

KVC does what you're trying to do, but it does it a lot better than you're likely to do it.

https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/KeyValueCoding/index.html

Answer (score 0):

I think your problem might occur with "int status", because dictionary[@ "status"] is not of type int.

In your code implementation,user.status = dictionary[@ "status"],this result is unpredictable.

Unless you make a type judgment, user.status = [dictionary[@ "status"]intValue];

I recommend a third-party framework on github called MJExtension that fulfills your needs.You can look at the source code.

Comment: The API response is strictly typed - so I do not have that overhead. Thanks for your response.